# Sort Nested List In Flutter

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart

I have a nested Json of products that I would like to sort by their price that is nested within the json structure. Right now when I try to sort via price, I get an error and I don't understand the error:

```
Class 'List<Product>' has no instance getter 'sizes'.
Receiver: Instance(length:5) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: sizes
```

If I'm trying to sort the nested filter, shouldn't I call sizes? I cannot get cases 1 or 2 working.

I'm trying filter my like this:

```
  void _sortProductsDropDown(_fabSort) {
    var tempProducts;

    setState(() {
      switch (_fabSort) {
        case 0:
tempProducts = [];
          break;
        case 1:
          tempProducts =
              filteredProducts.sizes.sort((a, b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price));

          print('Attempt $tempProducts');

          break;
        case 2:
          tempProducts = filteredProducts
              .Sodium.sort;
          print('Sodium sort + ${tempProducts.length}');

          break;
        case 3:
          tempProducts =
              filteredProducts.where((e) => e.caloriesContent == 0.0).toList();
          print(‘no cal  ${tempProducts}');

          break;
      }
    });
  }
```

My json data

```
            "id": 49,
            "name": “Celery Combo”,
            "short_description": “Yummy no calories”,

            "quantity": 26,
            "sizes": [
                {
                    "id": 47,
                    "size": 6,
                    "product_id": 49,
                    "price": 8.99
                }
            ],
            "image": "https://ges3334.amazonaws.com/product_images/
            “sodium,”: 7.0
        },
        {
            "id": 48,
            "name": “Beef Burger“,
            "short_description": “Mad Cow Calories”,

            "quantity": 30,
            "sizes": [
                {
                    "id": 46,
                    "size": 6,
                    "product_id": 48,
                    "price": 8.99
                }
            ],
            "image": "https://ges3334.amazonaws.com/product_images/single_cRIoNU8.png",


            “calorie”: 1200.0,
            “sodium”: 26.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The error is clear: `List<Product>` does not have `sizes` property, `sizes` is propery of each product. Is is unclear what you arevtrying to accomplish: to sort `sizes` list in each product, or to sort products by price in `sizes` (But what if there are multiple sizes in a product?)

Comment: Sort by the first item in sizes to show all product by the lowest prices. This way I can update the data in a list builder.

Answer (score 1):

List does not have sizes property, sizes is property of each product. This is generated by this line

```
filteredProducts.sizes.sort((a, b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price));
```

and clearly reported:

```
Class 'List<Product>' has no instance getter 'sizes'.
Receiver: Instance(length:5) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: sizes
```

In your comment, you say that you want to sort products by price, where price of Product is found by looking at first item in `sizes` list.

It is easy to achieve (here I used helper function, but a lambda is also ok):

```
int compareProductBySmallestSize(Product lhs, Product rhs) {
  var lhsPrice = lhs.sizes[0].price;
  var rhsPrice = rhs.sizes[0].price;
  return lhsPrice.compareTo(rhsPrice);
}

void _sortProductsDropDown(_fabSort) {
   // ...
   products.sort(compareProductBySmallestSize);
   // ...
}
```

Note that if products with empty `sizes` list are allowed, a small amendment must be made in the helper function.

Comment: How would you pass the results of the function?

Comment: Which function?

Comment: Do I access the data from    products.sort(compareProductBySmallestSize)?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. It returns a null value. With valid data.

Comment: List.sort() does not return anything, it sorts the list itself. See https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/List/sort.html. It returns void, not null. I’m afraid i still don’t get your problem